# sh -c and process substitution

Tags: bash, sh, iptables

In terminal (bash) the following works fine:

```
cat <(echo "hello")
```

But if I do:

```
sh -c 'cat <(echo "hello")'
```

I get

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Can you explain the reason why?

Btw, my overall aim is to write this command in a shell script:

```
watch -n 1 'cat <(iptables -L INPUT) <(iptables -L FORWARD)'
```

but it won't work, the reason seems to be the above problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sh` is often `dash` not `bash` (see `man sh`).
`dash` doesn't do process substitution, only POSIX stuff.

You'll need to do:

```
  bash -c 'cat <(echo "hello")'
```

`ksh` & `zsh` can do process substitution too.

With your example, you can simply do:

```
watch -n 1  'iptables -L INPUT;  iptables -L FORWARD'
```

no need for an advanced shell or process subtitution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the syntax error is that `sh` is not linked to `bash` on your system and does not understand [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), which is not part of the POSIX standard.

I would recommend the following command which is much cleaner and works with any POSIX compatible shell:

```
while true ; do
    clear
    iptables -L INPUT
    iptables -L FORWARD
    sleep 1
done
```